# Is there a way to use an IF function to shade other cells?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Here is the function I'm attempting to write:

[image: Here is the function I'm attempting to write]

I just want to know if it's possible. I've been searching for a similar issue but it doesn't seem very common

Comment: Yes, use **Conditional Formatting** which is available in Excel 2007 and later versions of Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Conditional Formatting based on a formula, with formulas like this

- Green: `=SUMIF($E$1:$E$9,A1,$F$1:$F$9)>10`
- Red: `=SUMIF($E$1:$E$9,A1,$F$1:$F$9)<=10`

You can use `SUMIF`, or `VLOOKUP`, or `INDEX/MATCH`, whatever you prefer, with your lookup table in `E1:F9`. Just test the results against your threshold of `10`.

[image]